# shared_ptr to keep graphical elements alive

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I am quite new to smart pointers but I think I am on the right path but can't seem to get this to work out.

I have a base object

```
class base_graphical_item
```

and another object derived from the base object

```
class derived_graphical_item
```

I have a factory class that creates derived grapical items and is inherited from a base factory class with a create function.

```
template <class T>
class item_factory
{
    public:
        virtual ~item_factory(){};
        std::shared_ptr<T> create(item_manager manager){};

};

template <>
class item_factory<derived_graphical_item>
{
    public:
        item_factory<derived_graphical_item>(){};
        ~item_factory<derived_graphical_item>(){};
        std::shared_ptr<derived_graphical_item> create(item_manager manager){
                std::shared_ptr<base_graphical_item> sg = std::make_shared<derived_graphical_item>();
                manager.register_item(sg);
                return std::static_pointer_cast<derived_graphical_item>(sg);
            };
};
```

The reference to manager is where my question begins. The goal is to create a reference to a graphical object that can be returned and is kept alive in the manager until it is requested to be removed from the display. My manager looks like this currently:

```
class item_manager
{
    public: 
        void register_item(std::shared_ptr<base_graphical_item>& base_item)
        {
            m_items.emplace_back(base_item);
        }
    private:
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<base_graphical_item>> m_items;
};
```

I am expecting that the item will be allocated and referenced by the shared pointer (use_count = 1) after passing it to the register function where it is added to the vector containing all of the created items I expect the use_count to increment to 2. The returned created item is passed up to higher function that draws the item.

If I use the destructor of the base item to "un-draw" the item, then the item is never drawn because it is immedetly destroyed after the drawing function returns.

```
  ~base_graphical_item()
    {
        destroy_graphical_item();
    }
```

The higher level drawing function looks something like this:

```
void helix_interface::initalize(void)
{
   ...
    auto factory = new item_factory<derived_graphical_item>();
    auto item = factory->create(m_manager);
    single_gauge->draw(m_tile_view);
    ...
}
```

Comment: You're passing a copy of your `item_manager` to `create`, which gets destroyed when the function returns.  You need a reference.

Comment: Thank you!!! I don't know how I missed that. I guess I was way too focused on the whole new smart pointer thing to remember the basics. Please make this an answer so I can give you the credit!

Comment: It's tough to find the question being asked. You have "where my question begins" labeled, but not where it ends -- not even with a question mark. Everything kind of blends together into the description of your goal, making it hard to distinguish where you transition from goal to symptom. *On a related note, there should be no need for labeling "where my question begins". You should start asking the question at the beginning of the post (c.f. [ask]). It shouldn't take a lot of explanation to describe the symptoms, should it?*

Comment: You probably can simplify some of your code: In your `create` function you store the `shared_ptr` to base and then cast it back for returning. Also in the code posted the template specialization seems unnecessary.